# ¿Porque todo el tráfico pasa por la zona public?

Tags: centos, firewall

Tengo un servidor con CentOs 7.3 con la "minimal", con dos tarjetas de red, em1 y p1p1. em1 tiene asignada la ip 192.168.1.100 y p1p1 la ip 192.168.1.130. También tienen las zonas de firewall asignadas, em1 está en la zona work y p1p1 está en la zona public.

Mi pregunta es: si me conecto por putty a 192.168.1.100 o a 192.168.1.130, ¿porque me asigna todo el trafico a la zona public?.

Lo sé porque si le quito el servicio ssh a la zona public no me puedo conectar de ninguna de las formas y haga lo que haga con la zona work no afecta.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Vale, despues de un rato veo que el problema está en como están definidas las nic en el ifcfg. Alguna idea de que debo mirar!!

Comment: Dos ips en la misma subred (asumo que el mask es el estandard) para dos placas en la misma maquina... y en distintas zonas? no parece una estructura de red sana.

Comment: Gracias @leonbloy por tu respuesta. Mi idea es que el tráfico exterior (internet) pase a través de una zona del firewall (public) y el tráfico interno por otra (work), por eso asigno cada nic a una zona. Al estar detras de un NAT las dos tarjetas tienen la misma subnet.... ya veo que solo son problemas. Esto está pensado para no estar detras de un NAT. ¿verdad?

Answer (score 1):

(Eso debería ser un comentario y no una respuesta, pero aún no puedo hacer comentarios)

Tres comentarios:

- Creo que tener un host con dos interfaces en la misma red (asumo que tanto la interface con IP 192.168.1.100 y interface con IP 192.168.1.130 tienen la misma máscara /24, y por ende están en la misma red) y considerarlas zonas diferentes en el firewall sólo te ocasionará dolores de cabeza y problemas muy difíciles de encontrar y resolver. La mayor parte de los scripts y sistemas de firewall usan las zonas como etiquetas para facilitar la comprensión del operador, y luego las reglas en el kernel se expresan  por `ipsets`, con lo que puede que se genern reglas contradictorias o que no surgen el efecto esperado.
- Independientemente del firewall, cuando el server debe responder a una petición va a enrutar el tráfico según su tabla de ruteo, que puedes revisar con `ip route`. Apuesto que en tu caso tiene primero en su lista para destinos a `192.168.10/24` a la interface que tu ves que siempre devuelve el tráfico.
- Nuevamente independientemente de por donde vuelva el tráfico de SSH, quizás sea más sencillo (y más seguro) configurar el servicio SSH para que sólo escuche en la interface que tu deseas, y no usar el firewall para forzar eso.

Espero que sea de ayuda!

Comment: +1 De acuerdo con todo.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo. El ssh es un ejemplo que he usado para poder expresarme facilmente. Lo que quiero es controlar que el tráfico por una nic sólo sea permitido por los puertos 80 / 8080 / 43 por ejemplo y el 22 / 3306 solo sea permitido por la otra nic. ¿Serviría que cada nic estuviera en una red diferente (192.168.1.100 y 192.168.2.100)?.